# Swap Image On Scroll

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I want to be able to swap the logo image from a light image to a dark image when I scroll up or down at X number of pixels. I'm also doing this in Wordpress without removing the PHP in the image source. I'm just adding the file name after the PHP WordPress function when scrolled. Here's the code:

HTML

```
  <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/logo_lighttext.svg" id="main-logo">
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
  var logoDefault,
      mainLogo = document.getElementById('main-logo');

  logoDefault = mainLogo.src.concat('/img/logo_lighttext.svg');
  mainLogo.src = logoDefault;

  function replaceImage(imageFile) {
    var concatImgFile = mainLogo.src.concat('/img/' + imageFile);
    return concatImgFile;
  }

  function swapImageOnScroll() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 150 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 150) {
      mainLogo.src = replaceImage('logo_lighttext.svg');
    } else {
      mainLogo.src = replaceImage('logo_darktext.svg');
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener('scroll', swapImageOnScroll);
```

It adds the file name, but every time I scroll up or down in the browser it's doing this odd behavior.

```
  <img src="http://macbook-pro.local:5757/wp-content/themes/wordpress/img/logo_lighttext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_darktext.svg/img/logo_lighttext.svg/img/logo_lighttext.svg/img/logo_lighttext.svg/img/logo_lighttext.svg/img/logo_lighttext.svg/img/logo_lighttext.svg/img/logo_lighttext.svg/img/logo_lighttext.svg/img/logo_lighttext.svg/img/logo_lighttext.svg" alt="Logo" class="main-logo" id="main-logo"></img>
```

Comment: I think it's better to use the inline svg, and when scrolling to the dark section, change svg class to the dark, and when you scroll to the light one, enter it. And add the appropriate styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read about how [concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat) works. It concatenates which means it combines the strings together. You are continually building a longer and longer string every time you scroll. If you want to replace the src text you should simply use `mainLogo.src = 'path'`.

```
var darkImage = '/img/logo_darktext.svg';
var lightImage = '/img/logo_lighttext.svg';
var mainLogo = document.getElementById('main-logo');
var directory = mainLogo.src;

function swapImageOnScroll() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 150 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 150) {
    mainLogo.src = directory + lightImage;
  } else {
    mainLogo.src = directory + darkImage;
  }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', swapImageOnScroll);
```

Comment: I need it to have this function <?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>  stay. 

The reason I thought to use concat() is that from what I understand is that all HTML attribute values are strings 
https://javascript.info/dom-attributes-and-properties#html-attributes

I thought since both are strings I was concatenating the HTML value string to another string.  I just wasn’t expecting the odd behavior with the onScroll event. 

Is there another way to keep that PHP function in place?

Comment: @Ginz77 Sure, you can store the directory like you were before and then just add the image path to the end of it. I've updated the answer.